# Add nofollow to javascript footer?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to add rel=nofollow to all taxonomies on my page. An example of such taxanomies are tags.

I have found that such tags appear in the footer of my website. These tags are added to each blog posts to help categorize them. Example:

```
<footer class="article-tags entry-footer"><div> <strong>Tags:</strong>
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/tag/diet/" title="">Diet</a>, 
<a href="https://mywebsite.com/tag/exercise/" title="">Exercise</a></div></footer>
```

Thus, in the above example, there are two tags ie. Diet and Exercise.

Is there an easy way to implement this using javascript?

I currently tried this out and it works but was wondering if there is a way to carry this out in javascript? Jquery seems to give problems to my wordpress theme.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.entry-footer a').attr('rel','nofollow')
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4az2y8xv/

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `setAttribute` method to add `rel=nofollow`.

Comment: Try this once  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/16439/a-plugin-for-having-rel-nofollow-in-posts

Comment: It would make sense for those links to be rel="tag" instead, https://www.w3.org/TR/html/links.html#link-type-tag

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the replies. I am on the way home and would try out what you all said when I reach home.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I believe your question is not as enough as clear. but I guess you should use JavaScript method to do what you want:

```
const anchors = document.querySelectorAll('a');
anchors.forEach( a => a.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow') );
```

After running above code all of your `a` tags has `nofollow` rel.

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have edited my question for clarity. May I know if it is clearer? Also, for your code, is there a way to target `a` tags only in the `footer` class of the page? My concern is that it would affect `a` tags elsewhere on the page.

Comment: I have tried out your code and it does not seem to work. My `a` tags do not show 'nofollow` rel

Comment: Dear @Confusedstudent, what does it mean _do not show_? because after running my code you can inspect and see anchors has nofollow rel.